# Firefox and IE fail again Help make my code cross browser? JQuery Auto scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, jquery-animate

I'm having trouble getting this to work In IE and Firefox and it only works in chrome what it is... is the page auto scrolls from top to bottom and then back again over and over with 2 buttons one to stop the "animation" and another to start it again.. 
Anyways here it is, Iv also attached a live link at the bottom of the question..

HTML :

```
<div id="Stage_About" class="Stage_About_id" style="position: absolute; margin: 0px; left: 0px; top: 2248px; width: 100%; height: 1169px; right: auto; bottom: auto; background-size: 100%; background-image: url(http://www.hd-wallpapers.com/download/blue-background_1600x1200_224-standard.jpg); -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0); background-position: 0px 0px; background-repeat: no-repeat no-repeat;"></div>

<div id="Stage_Hello" class="Stage_Hello_id" style="position: absolute; margin: 0px; left: 0px; top: 685px; width: 100%; height: 982px; right: auto; bottom: auto; background-size: 100%; background-image: url(http://www.wallgc.com/images/2013/01/black-windows-7-psdgraphics.jpg); -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0); background-position: 0px 0px; background-repeat: no-repeat no-repeat;"></div>

<div id="Stage_play" class="Stage_play_id" style="position: fixed; margin: 0px; left: 4%; top: 78px; width: 218px; height: 104px; right: auto; bottom: auto; border: 0px none rgb(0, 0, 0); background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0); -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);"></div>

<div id="Stage_stop" class="Stage_stop_id" style="position: fixed; margin: 0px; left: 79.3%; top: 78px; width: 208px; height: 88px; right: auto; bottom: auto; border: 0px none rgb(0, 0, 0); background-color: rgb(98, 98, 98); -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);"></div>

<div style="height:2000px; float:left; width:100%;">
TEXT 
TEXT
TEXT
TEXTTEXT 
TEXT
TEXT
TEXTTEXT 
TEXT
TEXT
TEXTTEXT 
TEXT
TEXT
TEXTTEXT 
TEXT
TEXT
TEXTTEXT 
TEXT
TEXT
TEXTTEXT 
TEXT
TEXT
TEXTTEXT 
TEXT
TEXT
TEXTTEXT 
TEXT
TEXT
TEXTTEXT 
TEXT
TEXT
TEXTTEXT 
TEXT
TEXT
TEXTTEXT 
TEXT
TEXT
TEXTTEXT 
TEXT
TEXT
TEXTTEXT 
TEXT
TEXT
TEXTTEXT 
TEXT
TEXT
TEXT

</div>
```

Jquery:

```
$("body").append($("#Stage_stop").css("position", "fixed"));
$("body").append($("#Stage_play").css("position", "fixed"));

function updown(){
  var bottom = $(document).height()-$(window).height();
  $('body')
    .animate({scrollTop:bottom},20000)
    .animate({scrollTop:0},2000,updown);
}
updown();

/* Stop animation */
$("#Stage_stop").click(function(){
    $('body').stop(true);
});

/* Start animation */
$("#Stage_play").click(function(){
    updown();
});
```

Live Example ONLY works in Chrome ! not firefox or IE.
[Example Link](http://jsfiddle.net/MAGG0T/CsqGr/2/)

Comment: why do you have reams of css in-line?

Comment: Because it works either way plus this is a rough copy of what i'm trying to do...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Scroll the HTML element as well:

```
  $('html, body')
    .animate({scrollTop:3000},20000)
    .animate({scrollTop:0},2000,updown);
```

and also

```
 $('html, body').stop(true);
```

on the button.

Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/CsqGr/5/  (Also note I changed the jquery to edge, as there is a bug in 1.10.1 that causes problems with IE 10).

Comment: Thanks alot that did it, I also needed   $('html, body').stop(true); on the #Stage_stop button.